# How do I pass the useState variable setSubTitle from one component to another component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I use the setSubTitle in ReportHeader.js?

#### **ReportHeader.js**

```
const ReportHeader = ({ cpId, capabilitypackname }) => {}
```

## **DashBoard.js**

```
function Dashboard(props) {
    const [subTitle, setSubTitle] = useState(SUBTITLES.default);
    setSubTitle(SUBTITLES[location.pathname] || SUBTITLES.default);
    if (location.pathname === `${PATH_TO_SM_PROFILE}/${profileId}`) {
        setSubTitle('Stakeholder Profile')
    }
    else 
        if (location.pathname === `${PATH_TO_CAPABILITY_PACK}/${reportid}`) {
            setSubTitle('Test');
}
```

Comment: I want to pass capabilitypackname in the subtitle instead of 'Test'

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the capabilitypackname prop to the ReportHeader component and use it to update the subtitle of the report header.

Here’s an example:

```
import React from 'react';

const ReportHeader = ({ cpId, capabilitypackname, setSubTitle }) => {
  const handleSubtitleChange = (event) => {
    setSubTitle(capabilitypackname);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{capabilitypackname}</h1>
      <input type="text" onChange={handleSubtitleChange} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ReportHeader;
```

Here, I am passing the capabilitypackname prop to the ReportHeader component and using it to update the subtitle of the report header when the user types something in the input field.